# Velocity self-advection stability problem with QUICK upwind scheme

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to implement a finite-difference fluid solver (incompressible, inviscous) using the QUICK scheme for advection. Mostly I've been following the Norris thesis chapter 2 (https://ses.library.usyd.edu.au/handle/2123/376) for the math.

It got advection of scalar fields to be stable and non-oscillating by using Adams-Bashforth (AB2) time integration and applying the ULTRA flux-limiter of Leonard.

The code breaks down, though, when applying this advection scheme to the velocity field itself. In particular at the domain boundaries (using open/zero-pressure boundary conditions) oscillations appear. In 1D the oscillation amplitude seems to stay limited, but in 2D diverging modes appear at the domain corners.

I tried a variety of methods of boundary cell handling without success.

Is it necessary to modify the QUICK/AB2 scheme as such for velocity self-advection?

I can post visualizations if helpful.